# Error with the_role gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails

At this time I'm tryng to use "the_role" gem with "sorcery" and I'm following this documentation: https://github.com/the-teacher/the_role/wiki/Integration-with-Sorcery

I finished all the steps but the gem is not working

When I try to apply it in a view like this

```
<% if current_user.has_role?(:polls, :new) %>

<% end %>
```

I get this error:

```
undefined method `to_hash' for nil:NilClass
```

I'm using `gem "the_role", "~> 1.6.0"` and rails 4

I also followed this documentation `https://github.com/the-teacher/the_role` but I see like is incomplete

Thanks for your help

Comment: Have you restarted your Rails server?

Comment: post the complete stacktrace